# Number of intersections between 2 date ranges

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, range

I have 2 date ranges in my Codeigniter App, and i want to calculate the number of days that intersects between those to ranges. any ideas?

Date1start = YYYY-MM-DD;
Date1end = YYYY-MM-DD;

Date2start = YYYY-MM-DD;
Date2end = YYYY-MM-DD;

Comment: "*number of days that intersects between those to ranges*" - Could you explain what that means?

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you show us your code please ? @AmalMurali he wants to know how many days belong to both date ranges.

Comment: yes i want to find the overlap.

Comment: You should provide some example and the code you tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
$datetimeStart1 = new DateTime('2015-12-10');
$datetimeEnd1 = new DateTime('2015-12-20');

$datetimeStart2 = new DateTime('2015-12-12');
$datetimeEnd2 = new DateTime('2015-12-28');

// following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap
if ($datetimeStart1 < $datetimeEnd2 && $datetimeEnd1 > $datetimeStart2) {
    echo min($datetimeEnd1,$datetimeEnd2)->diff(max($datetimeStart2,$datetimeStart1))->days+1;
} else {
    echo 'no overlap';
}
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/9Pecb

**Only for PHP 5.2**

```
$datetimeStart1 = new DateTime('2015-12-10');
$datetimeStart1 = $datetimeStart1->format('U');
$datetimeEnd1 = new DateTime('2015-12-20');
$datetimeEnd1 = $datetimeEnd1->format('U');

$datetimeStart2 = new DateTime('2015-12-12');
$datetimeStart2 = $datetimeStart2->format('U');
$datetimeEnd2 = new DateTime('2015-12-28');
$datetimeEnd2 = $datetimeEnd2->format('U');

// following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap
if ($datetimeStart1 < $datetimeEnd2 && $datetimeEnd1 > $datetimeStart2) {
    echo round(
        ((min($datetimeEnd1,$datetimeEnd2)) - (max($datetimeStart2,$datetimeStart1))) / (60*60*24)) + 1;
} else {
    echo 'no overlap';
}
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/a1WLk

Comment: thank you for answering, i have tried your code and got the (Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() ) error.

Comment: What's version of php are you using? =< 5.2?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a possible workaround for php 5.2. But you should totally upgrade your php version.

Answer (score 4):

Write it easy:

```
$datetimeStart1 = new DateTime('2015-12-10');
$datetimeEnd1 = new DateTime('2015-12-20');

$datetimeStart2 = new DateTime('2015-12-12');
$datetimeEnd2 = new DateTime('2015-12-28');

$start = max($datetimeStart2,$datetimeStart1);
$end = min($datetimeEnd1,$datetimeEnd2);
echo $end >= $start ? $end->diff($start)->days+1 : "no overlap";
```